# jqGrid multiselect "check all" in header: how to hide it?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, checkbox

I use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) with the multiselect option set to true.

I'm looking for a way to hide or disable the first checkbox (the one in the row of the column names) so that users can't use the "check all/uncheck all" feature.

How to do it?

Answer (score 25):

The checkbox in the header has the id which is combined from the "cb_" prefix and the grid id. So you can hide the element with

```
var myGrid = $("#list");
$("#cb_"+myGrid[0].id).hide();
```

Comment: This is the best way I've found to do this.

Comment: What if the target list does not has an id?

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari: I don't understand your question. What "target list" you mean?

Comment: @Oleg I meant converting a table with no id (`<table class="x">`) to a jqgrid, but apparently jqgrid requires the `<table>` to have an id.

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari: Sorry, but my answer was **about jqGrid**. *You can't create grid from `<table>` element which has no `id`*. It's one from base requirement of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Find the div of checkbox and hide/overwrite its inner HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have runat parameter

```
<trirand:JQGrid ID="grdTest" runat="server" 
"MultiSelect="true" MultiSelectMode="SelectOnRowClick">
    <Columns>
    <!-- cols -->
    </Columns>

     <ClientSideEvents GridInitialized="GrdInit" /><!-- add this -->
    </trirand:JQGrid>
```

On your page:

```
function getCont(control)
{
    if(control == "grdTest")
    { 
       return $("#<%= grdTest.ClientID %>"); 
    }
}
```

Then in your js file:

```
function GrdInit() 
{ 
    var myGrid = getCont("grdTest"); 
    myGrid.jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb'); 
}
```