# How do I hide all the checkboxes in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need to hide all the checkboxes on a jQgrid and after read this two posts:

- [Remove the heading checkbox from jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897765/remove-the-heading-checkbox-from-jqgrid)
- [jqGrid multiselect "check all" in header: how to hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212571/jqgrid-multiselect-check-all-in-header-how-to-hide-it/6213082#6213082)

This is what I did:

```
// this only hides the first checkbox on the header
$('#gbox_grid_notification_queue').find('input[type="checkbox"]').hide();

// this does not hide anything at all
$('#gbox_grid_notification_queue').find('td input[type="checkbox"]').hide();

// this does not hide anything, same as previous one
var grid_notification_queue = $("#grid_notification_queue");
$("#cb_" + grid_notification_queue.id).hide();
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: `$('#gbox_grid_notification_queue input[type="checkbox"]').hide();`

Comment: Does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, then the solution would be very easy. You need just add

```
multiselectPosition: "none"
```

option to **prevent** creating checkboxs. It improves additionally the performance of multi-selection. I remind that [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1135-L1151) you can find different options of free jqGrid, which has relation with selection. The value of `multiselectPosition` could be `"left"`, `"right"` or `"none"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
```

Comment: This code will hide all checkboxes in the page and not only in the grid

Comment: Yes.  Only add id grid inside selector. $("#gbox_grid_notification_queue input[type=checkbox]")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#gbox_grid_notification_queue').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
});
```