# Hiding right border of cell in header

Tags: jqgrid

Hi Is there any way to hide a cell border (right side) in jqgrid ?

Actual : [image]

Desired : 
[image]

PS : I want to leave all other borders intact (i just want to remove the checkbox's right border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirement you can add the following CSS rule. Let us you have the grid with `id="list"` then you can use

```css
#list_cb { border-right-color: transparent; }
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792322/315935) with a close problem.

Comment: @Olag can i ask one more question ?

Comment: @Joseph: Of cause. You can open new question for example.

Comment: @Olag it concerns this one in fact.

Comment: I have multiselect activated but i am looking to remove the check all checkbox from the header section , i can't seem to find a neat way to do it. ideally i would want to merge the first two columns (the checkbox's one and the one after 'Offre').

Comment: @Joseph: It's very easy. You need just execute `$("#cb_list").hide();` once after the grid is created. It hides the checkbox. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6213082/315935).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61282/discussion-between-joseph-and-oleg).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. I don't understand which **real problem** one have because of the cell exist? One can force hovering on the next cell inside of hovering on `#list_cb`, but I don't really see a problem.