# Center Checkbox in Header

Tags: html, css, jqgrid

I want to align: center the "select all" checkbox in the header. It is the first cell in the header of jqgrid.

I tried:

```
#configDiv th input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

and

```
grid.find('th input[type="checkbox"]').css("align", "center");
```

Those didn't work!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs, such as checkboxes, are inline elements and you can't centre them directly. You need to centre the "text" (I know a checkbox isn't text, but that is what the CSS rule is) in the parent element, in this case the `th`.

You can do that with the following code in your CSS;

```
#configDiv th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you need to target the particular `th` then you should add a class to the HTML and use the `th.classname` selector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post your HTML output (edit your question) so we can see if anything else is the problem. Don't post all of it, just the part around the checkbox.

Comment: I can't post image because I am new here!

Comment: No, copy and paste the code when you right click the page and select View Source Code (or whatever it is in your browser).

Comment: Yes. Hence why you should only post the relevant part. Look (or seach using Ctrl+F) for `<input type='checkbox'` (you may be using double quotes (`"`) instead of the single quotes I've used here).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212571/jqgrid-multiselect-check-all-in-header-how-to-hide-it/6213082#6213082) from Oleg I found this;

```
grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid-view').find('table.ui-jqgrid-htable th:first-child').css("text-align", "center");
```