# checked all checkbox in subGrid when checked checkbox in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have one JqGrid and one subGrid. All JqGrid and subGrid I set:

```
multiselect: true
```

When I checked one row from JqGrid I want automatic checked all row in subGrid like this image below:
[image]

Comment: You should post mode details, for example, *the JavaScript code of `subGridRowExpanded` callback*. It's important to know, which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's important to understand, that subgrids will by typically created on opening subgrid only, but one can change the behavior by `subGridOptions`.

Comment: If the subgrib *is already opened* and *the data are loaded*, then one can select rows by simulating `click` on the column header of the multiselect column (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6213082/315935)). On the other side if subgrid is still loading the data via Ajax request, then one have to do this later (in `loadComplete` for example). Free jqGrid allows *pre-select* rows, by filling `selarrrow` and the selection of all rows allows to select rows from *all local pages* (see the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021115/315935)).